# java backend for qooxdoo with the date hack

Tags: qooxdoo

is there a skeleton java backend (json rpc) for qooxdoo js framework?
Could any json RPC backend work for qooxdoo or we need the date hack to have it work?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: If you set the "protocol" property to "2.0", you should be able to interoperate with any standards-based JSON-RPC 2.0 server.

Detailed answer:

The qooxdoo JSON RPC client supports both its original protocol, a variation of JSON-RPC 1.0 called "qx1" (the default, for age-old backward compatibility), and the standardized JSON-RPC 2.0. You'll want to switch it to 2.0 by setting the "protocol" property to "2.0". If I recall correctly, our JSON-RPC client is then fully 2.0 standards-compliant except that we don't support batch requests.

Additionally, as you've noted, qooxdoo used to try to fix the "bug" in JSON/JavaScript, that there is no literal form for a Date object as there is for all other types in JavaScript. The qooxdoo JSON-RPC implementation has provisions for automatically converting Date objects into a string format that is easily parsed.

As of many years ago, we realized that it was poor form to muck with JSON-RPC since mucking with it allowed us to communicate only with qooxdoo-enhanced JSON-RPC servers. At that time, we changed the default to *not* do any date conversions. This is controlled by the static variable, qx.io.remote.Rpc.CONVERT_DATES, which can be set to true to "fix the bug" as we did originally, or left at its now default null (or false) value, which says "do not muck with dates."

That's all a long-winded answer to say that qooxdoo's JSON-RPC client, if you switch it to use the 2.0 protocol, should interoperate fine with any standards-based JSON-RPC 2.0 server.

Derrell

Comment: Thank you @Derrel for the detailed answer